# Why I am getting the table 4 times its size in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to edit a row of table containing `person` objects. My idea is to show the table and after clicking on the row to edit, the row changes to 2 textBoxes (`Name`and `surname`to edit) and a button to confirm edit operation. When I run the program the table shows 4 times its size(I have 4 rows) and when I click on a random row disappears 4 rows and the table becomes 3 times its size(12 rows).
What is causing the fail?  Thanks for your time
The code:

```
 class EditPersons extends React.Component {
           constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    editing: null
                };
                this.editPerson = this.editPerson.bind(this);
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                this.props.fetchData('http://localhost:9536/persons/');
            }
            editPerson(person) {
                this.setState(
                    { editing: person.PersonId }
                );
            }
            renderPersonOrEdit(person) {
                if (this.state.editing === person.PersonId) {
                    console.log('editing: ' + person.PersonId); //test ok
                    //Here comes the 2 textBoxes and the edit-button
                }
                else {
                    return (
                        <tbody>
                            {this.props.persons.map((person, i) => {
                                return(
                                    <tr key={i}>
                                        <td onClick={()=>this.editPerson.(person)}><Link>{person.Name}<Link></td>
                                        <td>{person.Surname}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })}
                        </tbody>
                    );
                }
            }
            render() {

                if (this.props.hasErrored) {
                    return <p>Downloading has failed!</p>;
                }

                if (this.props.isLoading) {
                    return <p>Downloading…</p>;
                }

                return (
                    <div>
                        <table id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Person name</th>
                                <th>Person Surname</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            {this.props.persons.map((person) => {
                                return this.renderPersonOrEdit(person);
                            })}
                        </table>
                        <Link to="/project" className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style={{marginTop: 20}}>Back</Link>
                    </div>

                );
            }
        }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
                personss: state.persons,
                hasErrored: state.personsHasErrored,
                isLoading: state.personsIsLoading
            };
        };

        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
            return {
                fetchData: (url) => dispatch(personsFetchData(url))
            };
        };

        EditPersons.propTypes = {
            fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            persons: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
            hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
        };

        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditPersons);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `render()` function you are already mapping over the elements and then in the `renderPersonOrEdit`  you are doing the same, change your code to map at only the render function

```js
class EditPersons extends React.Component {
           constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    editing: null
                };
                this.editPerson = this.editPerson.bind(this);
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                this.props.fetchData('http://localhost:9536/persons/');
            }
            editPerson(person) {
                this.setState(
                    { editing: person.PersonId }
                );
            }
            renderPersonOrEdit() {

                if (this.state.editing !== null) {
                    console.log('editing: ' + person.PersonId); //test ok
                    //Here comes the 2 textBoxes and the edit-button

                    //set editing to null after editing the contents
                }
                else {
                return <tbody>
                   {this.props.persons.map((person) => {
                        return (
                             <tr key={person.PersonId}>
                               <td onClick={()=>this.editPerson.(person)}><Link>{person.Name}<Link></td>
                                   <td>{person.Surname}</td>
                             </tr>
                        );
                   })}
                   </tbody>
                }
            }
            render() {

                if (this.props.hasErrored) {
                    return <p>Downloading has failed!</p>;
                }

                if (this.props.isLoading) {
                    return <p>Downloading…</p>;
                }

                return (
                    <div>
                        <table id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Person name</th>
                                <th>Person Surname</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {this.renderPersonOrEdit()}
                        </table>
                        <Link to="/project" className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style={{marginTop: 20}}>Back</Link>
                    </div>

                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri` I am getting `i is not defined` when i use `<tr key={i}>`. `i` was here (by side `person`): `{this.props.persons.map((person)`

Comment: Sorry mymistake, updated the code, for renderPersonOrEdit function

Comment: I get the normal size of table(4 rows), but when I click on the first row its disappears (table becomes 3 rows) and when i click on the second row its shows the content of row 1 and so one. The table is always with 3 rows!

Comment: What is that you want to happen instead, when you click on it, it disappears because for the rest isEditing value is set to this row and for the rest of the rows the map function return the row from renderPersonOrEdit function

Comment: See the updated code, that is a better method I think

Comment: I am very sorry. you are right. I forgot that instead for the row it will be editing-boxes. I need a break. Thanks for your help and your time. Very appreciated.

Comment: Tried your last solution. It is better and I prefer it.

Comment: You can use whatever best suits you, I thought of giving you two approaches